# jQuery confirmation of page leaving

Tags: javascript, jquery, warnings

I tried to use jQuery serialize to confirm user for form content change. It seems working. The issue is that before I submit the form, I reset the window.onbeforeload to null and hope it will not popup the confirmation dialog when user clicks submit button. But my code below still show the popup when submit button clicked.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery warn page leaving</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css">
<script src="../jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#form').data('serialize',$('#form').serialize());
}
  );

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e){
   if($('#form').serialize()!=$('#form').data('serialize'))
      return "Data changed.";
   else e=null;
   // i.e; if form state change show box not.
});

$("#form").submit( function() {
    alert("called submit");
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
 });

 function disableBeforeUnload() {
  alert ("call disable func");
  window.onbeforeunload = null;
}
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Go to google</a>

<form id="form" name='experiment' action="#" onsubmit="disableBeforeUnload();">
<Label for='firstName'>First name: </label><input name = 'fname' type="text" size="30" />

<Label for='firstName'>Last name: </label><input name = 'lname' type="text" size="30" />
<select name ='options'>
<option value=1> One</option>
<option value=2> two</option>
 <option value=3> three</option>
 </select>
 <button type="submit" name="submit" />
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it'll be better to use `unbind` function? Like following:

```
$("#form").submit( function() {
  alert("called submit");
  window.unbind('beforeunload')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unbind the jQuery handler, not the native onbeforeunload event. So use:

```
$(window).unbind('beforeunload');
```

Or now, preferred method is to use `off()` to unbind:

```
$(window).off('beforeunload');
```

And `on()` for binding instead of `bind()`. Be aware though that `bind()` and `unbind()` aren't deprecated, it's still ok to use it.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YrPc7/5/)